# Sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise, show that there exists $M$ such that $f_n(x) \le M$ on open set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

**Problem Statement:** Suppose that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $R$ converging to a function $f$ on $R$. Prove that there exists a non-empty open set $U$ of $R$ and a real number $M$ such that $|f_n(x)|\le M$ for all $x \in U$ and $n \ge 1$.

**My attempt at a solution:** I'm not sure how to proceed here - what I've done so far is: note that $f$ is measurable, since each continuous function is measurable, and messed around with sets of the form $E_M = \{x : |f_n(x)| \ge M \text{ for all } n\}$, trying to get some kind of intersection or union of those sets to be the set I want. But, I don't quite see how this should work, because I don't have that $f$ is integrable. I would really appreciate a hint in the right direction!

Comment: Maybe you are meant to use the Baire category theorem.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith oh, wow, I hadn't even thought about trying that. Would you be able to give me any hints on how to apply that to this problem?

Comment: Suppose that $E_n = \{x:|f_n(x)| \le M\}$ is nowhere dense for all $n$.  Then ....

Comment: Then we can't write $R$ as $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$? I'm sorry, I'm still pretty lost on this, I haven't worked with this theorem much. If you wanted to post a more detailed answer/hint as an answer, I would really appreciate it - just so you're not talking me through this in baby steps.

Comment: $\bigcup_n E_n$ must be nowhere dense.

Comment: So, this all makes sense, but to begin with, do we have to show that $\cup^\infty_{n=1}E_n = R$ to get the contradiction? I'm struggling with that part.

Comment: No, you just need to show the closure of $\cup E_n$ contains an open set for some $M>0$.